# SerializationException with WCF services

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, json

I have a WCF service set up as following:

```
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IObjectPresentationService
    {
        [OperationContract(Name="GetFooter")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
      BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
      ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)] 
        string GetFooter();
     }
```

When I use *Add Service Reference* on the client side, the following code is generated:

```
[System.ServiceModel.OperationContractAttribute(Action="http://tempuri.org/IObjectPresentationService/GetFooter", ReplyAction="http://tempuri.org/IObjectPresentationService/GetFooterResponse")]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetFooter();
```

However, when I try to execute GetFooter(), I get the following exception:

> **SerializationException was unhandled**
>   OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to
>   find an attribute with name 'type' and value 'object'. Found value
>   'string'.

Using Fiddler I can see that the service indeed returns a plain string, complete with quotemarks at the begining and end (which should make it valid json?).

Could this be an configuration issue?